# Meaning of "cohomology" in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I want to learn about different cohomologies in algebraic geometry with a view towards understanding the idea of motives. I'm more interested in starting with a general overview or history. The main thing I am confused about is that there seems to be two very different meanings of the word "cohomology". In Hartshorne, we are introduced to what I will call "coherent cohomology" via the derived functor of the global sections functor. Then we find that this agrees with Cech cohomology in most useful cases.

But it seems like in modern algebraic geometry, the term "cohomology" refers to Weil cohomology theories. Can the derived functor cohomology be made into a Weil cohomology? Does every Weil cohomology arise from a derived functor? Is the derived functor cohomology of Hartshorne worth studying these days, or is most work done in terms of Weil cohomology theories, or are they largely unrelated? In general I am trying to understand how etale, or crystalline cohomology, for example, relate both mathematically and historically to what I have learned from Hartshorne.

Comment: Étale cohomology is a derived functor cohomology, but not of a category of sheaves on a topological space.

Comment: Coherent cohomology is a tool for studying sheaves and their sections. You fix a scheme $X$, and then use this coh. theory to study various categories of sheaves on $X$. On the other hand, Weil coh. theories are used for studying categories of schemes, and are meant to function as replacements for singular coh.. To answer your last question, the two are somewhat unrelated in the sense that they study different types of objects. If a given question can be understood in terms of coherent coh., it just...doesn't really make sense to talk about "working in terms of Weil coh."

Comment: I agree with @TabesBridges.  The closest relationship I know of between sheaf cohomology and Weil cohomology theories is the Hodge-de Rham spectral sequence, which computes de Rham cohomology (a Weil cohomology theory if the base is a characteristic-0 field) in terms of sheaf cohomology of sheaves of differential forms.